# indirection requires pointer operand and expected expression errors

Tags: compilation, c++

I keep getting errors similar to these:

```
pitstop.cpp:36:23: error: indirection requires pointer operand

        ('double' invalid)

         cost = UNLEADED * gallons;

                          ^ ~~~~~~~

pitstop.cpp:40:14: error: expected expression

                    cost = SUPER * gallons;                               ^
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#define UNLEADED 3.45;
#define SUPER {UNLEADED + 0.10};
#define PREMIUM {SUPER + 0.10};

/* 
    Author: Zach Stow
    Date: 
    Homework 
    Objective:
*/

double cost, gallons;
string gasType, finish, stop;

int main()
{
    for(;;)

    {

        cout <<"Hi, welcome to Pitstop.\n"; 
        cout <<"Enter the type of gas you need:";
        cin >> gasType; 
        cout << endl;

        cout <<"Enter the amount of gallons you need:";
        cin >> gallons;
        cout << endl;

        if(gasType == "finish" || gasType == "stop")break;

        else if(gasType == "UNLEADED")
        {
            cost = UNLEADED * gallons;
        }
        else if(gasType == "SUPER")
        {
            cost = SUPER * gallons;
        }   
        else if(gasType == "PREMIUM")
        {
            cost = PREMIUM * gallons;
        }

    }   
    cout <<"You need to pay:$" << cost << endl;

    return(0);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please try to make a minimal version of your code demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a `c++` expert, but I'm sure that to define a constant you just need to use the `#define` directive followed by the symbol and by the value you want to assign to it (even if the value itself is an expression, even if such expression is referencing another constant), the braces and the trailing semicolon are excessive:

```c
// [...]

#define UNLEADED 3.45
#define SUPER (UNLEADED + 0.10)
#define PREMIUM (SUPER + 0.10)

//[...]
```

It compiled at the first attempt with such corrections.

Comment: You should wrap arithmetic expressions in parentheses I think (**not** braces, as the OP had) e.g. `#define SUPER (UNLEADED + 0.10)` to ensure associativity of expressions such as `SUPER * x`

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, that was more of a mathematical slip. Shame on me.

Comment: My math is rusty too - I probably should have said *distributivity* rather than *associativity* ;)

Comment: Also @ZachStow consider moving the `if` conditional right after having stored the user input in `gasType`: as it stands now is definetly *not* user-friendly, you always have to type a dummy value at the second input prompt even if you typed "finish" already

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the error is the semi colon at the end of the #define directive.

You have also used the incorrect type of brackets, try this instead:

`#define UNLEADED 3.45`

`#define SUPER (UNLEADED + 0.10)`

`#define PREMIUM (SUPER + 0.10)`

Note that when you use the #define directive whatever follows #define is substituted into your code. In this case after the preprocessor ran your code looked like this:

`else if(gasType == "UNLEADED")
{
    cost = UNLEADED 3.45; * gallons;
}
else if(gasType == "SUPER")
{
    cost = {UNLEADED + 0.10}; * gallons;
}

else if(gasType == "PREMIUM")
{
    cost = PREMIUM {SUPER + 0.10}; * gallons;
}`

The reason you were getting the `indirection requires pointer operand` error was the compiler trying to interpret this statement:

`* gallons;`

Because the `*` operator only has a single argument it is interpreted as a pointer dereference, luckily for you the `gallons` variable is not a pointer type. If gallons had been declared as a pointer type i.e. `double cost, *gallons;` and the `cin` wasn't there the code would compile but not do what you expect, probably throwing a segfault.

Macros defined with #define can be very powerful and very dangerous. There is usually a better way to achieve things in c++. In this case `UNLEADED`, `SUPER_UNLEADED` and `PREMIUM` could be declared as `const double` type i.e.

`const double unleaded = 3.45;
const double super = unleaded + 0.10;
const double premium = super + 0.10;`